# catching the samsung's s-view intent

Tags: android-intent, samsung-mobile

I want to make an app that will do something each time the s-view cover will open or close.

a thing like : launch a certain application everytime the s-view cover opens. 
anybody knows how can I catch the events of this cover?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the broadcast intents:
com.samsung.cover.OPEN or
com.samsung.ssrm.COVER_OPEN

In the extras, coverOpen will tell you if the cover opened or closed.

I found this by using dumpsys activity, and looking at the historical broadcasts for anything containing samsung.

Comment: How would you tell if the cover has already been closed when you register the broadcast receiver?